# Need Help Figuring Out Why Text Is Overflowing My Page

Tags: html, css

Like the title says, I am having issues with a VERY long string overflowing my page. I tried some overflow techniques, but none seem to work.

I had previously posted this as a Primefaces problem, but have since learned that it is not a Primefaces issue. Anyway, if anybody has any suggestions on how I can fix this, I would appreciate it. I will post my HTML below so you can see what I am talking about.

Thanks for taking the time to read, and have a great day.    :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> overflow </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container{
                width: 800px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                background-color: #efefef;
            }
            div {
                padding: 10px;
            }
            span.text {
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3> overflow </h3>
        <div id="container">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_X</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Y</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Z</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_X</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Y</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Z</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text">asdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_X</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Y</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Z</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text">asdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_X</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Y</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Z</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text">asdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_X</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Y</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell_Z</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text">asdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed semper justo vel felis blandit ut egestas nisi tincidunt. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc in est pulvinar orci pharetra fringilla in eget quam. Maecenas id ipsum eget arcu tempus varius eu sit amet neque. Praesent quis consectetur ligula. Nam bibendum, turpis nec dignissim euismod, arcu libero sodales sapien, ut scelerisque magna risus eu orci. Curabitur sit amet turpis at turpis adipiscing luctus nec id felis. Vestibulum luctus mauris quis ante dignissim rutrum. Fusce fermentum enim quis nisl volutpat consequat. Integer lacinia tempor nisi id aliquet. Praesent vitae semper ipsum. Curabitur mauris est, faucibus eu auctor a, egestas vitae nisi.
            </div>
            <div>
                Donec fringilla laoreet leo, eu aliquet dolor mollis sed. Donec ligula turpis, vestibulum sed faucibus at, venenatis consequat turpis. Integer fringilla, ligula in consequat sodales, odio nunc vulputate nisi, non hendrerit dolor mauris sodales nulla. Nulla mattis iaculis nisi, quis lacinia massa dictum vitae. Fusce quis turpis neque, nec adipiscing tortor. Cras et nisi sem, at viverra lacus. Nam posuere odio non lacus facilisis condimentum. Ut ultricies, arcu eget tempus facilisis, urna dui commodo neque, a posuere libero mi ut nisl. Praesent ut semper lectus. Aenean id mauris nulla. Pellentesque dapibus congue varius. Ut id turpis consequat augue pellentesque egestas. Nunc feugiat bibendum tortor, sit amet fringilla enim viverra in. Mauris sit amet lorem eget enim ultrices euismod id eu velit. Duis eu vestibulum sapien.
            </div>
            <div>
                Vivamus volutpat interdum tortor et luctus. Etiam laoreet congue nunc in congue. Nullam interdum mauris eros. Duis at turpis odio, in interdum odio. Aenean feugiat est at libero hendrerit quis laoreet purus egestas. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sagittis scelerisque venenatis. Morbi tristique rutrum tortor at lobortis. Suspendisse suscipit purus vel massa laoreet vitae dapibus lorem imperdiet. Mauris consectetur arcu et diam iaculis et cursus leo ultrices. Nunc turpis nunc, interdum ac pretium id, facilisis quis libero.
        </div>
        <div>
                Donec eget velit in nisl posuere porttitor ut at nisl. Phasellus eros tortor, pretium at sollicitudin pellentesque, feugiat a tortor. Integer blandit viverra odio, id iaculis odio fringilla ac. Nulla dignissim fermentum lorem ac scelerisque. Vivamus iaculis augue eu sapien porta convallis. Nam faucibus, diam nec condimentum dapibus, erat arcu vehicula nisi, sed vehicula ante ante convallis ipsum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec quam elit, mattis pretium venenatis nec, vehicula ut tellus. Phasellus commodo pretium purus, non viverra erat auctor sed. Ut dui nisl, pellentesque nec placerat non, sagittis condimentum nunc. Donec varius tincidunt est eu consequat. Etiam ac nulla ut nibh sagittis vulputate. Nullam egestas risus eu nunc tincidunt a ultricies libero posuere. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas sagittis est nec tellus sodales porttitor.
        </div>
        <div>
                Nullam vulputate dui ac velit lobortis pellentesque eu a nisi. Maecenas vitae ligula dui, in imperdiet mi. Mauris commodo nisl eu eros sodales sed tempor leo auctor. Nam ornare varius arcu, at dictum ipsum volutpat nec. Aenean sagittis adipiscing hendrerit. Aenean at quam lacus. Donec malesuada bibendum vestibulum. Suspendisse lobortis pretium neque, vitae tempus felis interdum in. Aliquam sed metus in felis sodales interdum. Praesent malesuada nulla pretium arcu consectetur eu dictum lacus elementum. Ut dictum faucibus hendrerit.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want this text to word-wrap? or would you rather have a scrollbar?

Comment: I would prefer it to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> problem </title>
        <style type="text/css">
.main
{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
 overflow: scroll;

}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4> problem </h4>
        <div class="main">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>cell</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="troubleSpan">asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it does scroll, but I would prefer it to wrap and look a little more "natural".

Comment: increase height of the div and you will see a larger scrolling panel

Answer (score 0):

use the word-wrap:break word css attribute & give it an explicit width:

```
span .text{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    width:800px;
}
```

This property will only apply if the element has a visual rendering, is an inline element with explicit height/width, is absolutely positioned and/or is a block element.

Comment: Nope, sorry. Thank you, though.

Comment: Justin, still a no-go. Thank you.